# Comparison of search speed for B-Tree and Trie

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures, trie, b-tree

I am trying to find out which will be more efficient in terms of speed of search, whether trie or B-Tree. I have a dictionary of English words and I want to locate a word in that dictionary efficiently.

Comment: There is no question here. What have you tried so far, and where are you stuck?

Comment: "Actual speed" depends on "actual implementation" and "actual data". If you are looking for *theoretic* search time, B tree offers `O(|S|*logn)` times while trie offers `O(|S|)` time. where |S| is the string's length and `n` is the number of items in dictionary.

Comment: Regarding the first part, of my previous comment: Some consideration for real speed: size of data, its location (examples: RAM/flash/disk/distributed filesystem), distribution of seeks (Are some searches more frequent than others?) and much more.

Comment: @amit post your comment as answer so the OP can accept

Comment: @KaidulIslam done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "more efficient in time of search" you refer to theoretical time complexity, then B Tree offers `O(logn * |S|)`<sup>1</sup> time complexity for search, while a trie offers `O(|S|)` time complexity, where `|S|` is the length of the searched string, and `n` is the number of elements in dictionary.

If by "more efficient in time of search" you refer to actual real life run time, that depends on the actual implementation, actual data and actual search behavior. Some examples that might influence the answer:

- Size of data
- Storage system (for example: RAM/Flah/disk/distributed filesystem/...)
- Distribution of searches
- Code optimizations of each implementation
- (and much more)

---

(1) There are `O(logn)` comparisons, and each comparison takes `O(|S|)` times, since you need to traverse the entire string to decide which is higher (worst case analysis).

Comment: You mentioned O(logn) Comparisons. Do you assume that we are storing a dictionary word itself in every node of a B tree?  What is the basis for traversing the tree?

Comment: @Xylene23 The depth of `B` tree is `O(logn)`, in order to find if a node exists, in worst case, you need to go from root to leaf, which is logarithmic in number of nodes.

Comment: To find if a node exists, the algorithm has to make comparisons. In the case of dictionary words, do we store an entire word in every node, in which case we will have to do string comparison at every level. Or do we have to represent these words by numbers (integers) which can be compared faster than words.

Comment: @Xylene23 If you represent these strings as numbers, this is likely some hash function of them. If you go that path, you can just use a hash table, which also solves collision issues for you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what's your need. If you want to get the whole **subtree**, a `B+Tree` is your best choice because it is space efficient and also the branching factor of the B+ Tree affects its performance (the number of intermediary nodes). If h is the height of the tree, then `nmax ~~ bh`. Therefore **h ~~ log(nmax) / log(b)**.

With **n = 1 000 000 000** and **b = 100**, we have **h ~~ 5**. Therefore it means only **5** pointer dereferencing for going from the root to the leaf. It's more cache-friendly than a Trie.

But if you want to get the first `N` children from a **substree**, then a Trie is the best choice because you simply visit less nodes than in a B+ Tree scenario.
Also the word prefix completion is well handled by `trie`.